# activity being recreated even with android:configChanges="orientation"

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, screen-orientation

For the first time im trying to set a landscape orientation on my app. Im having so much problems cause it uses actionbar.tab's and service and i dont know very well yet how all of this will happens on each fragment specifically. The first problem i faced was the asynchrony between activity lifecycle and service, cause the service was unbind when the activity was already recreated. Then i tried to set android:configChanges="orientation" on my manifest to manually handle the events, but the activity stills recreating itself.
I dont know how i will handle so many details on orientation changes, the most of data and information i have to retrieve is on service, it guards my app state, but im not getting do it.
Please help me before i give up implementing this funcion on my app.

I will post some code.

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.irclient2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.irclient2.activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.irclient2.service.MyService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <!-- AS DUAS TAGS SEGUINTES SÃO APENAS PARA O FUNCIONAMENTO DO ADMOB -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ServiceConnection {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyService.log("Activity onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerlayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, Gravity.LEFT);

    registerReceivers();
    cancelaNotificacao(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Intent it = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    if (!MyService.RUNNING) {
        startService(it);
    }

    if (!bindService(it, this, 0)) {
        mensagemErro("Erro!",
                "Não foi possível conectar ao service. Fechando app.");
        finish();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    MyService.log("Activity onDestroy()");
    unregisterReceivers();
    unbindService(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    // /////////////////////// CASO PORTRAIT ///////////////////////////

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

    }

    // /////////////////////// CASO LANDSCAPE ///////////////////////////

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

    }

}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binderservice) {
    MyService.log("Activity onServiceConnected");
    LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) binderservice;
    this.service = binder.getService();

    carregaRadio();

    if (MyService.bot != null && MyService.bot.isConnected()) {
        carregaChatdoService();
        selectTab(TITLE_TAB_CHAT);
    } else {
        carregaLogin();
        selectTab(TITLE_TAB_RADIO);
    }

}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    service = null;

}

//////////// THERE ARE MORE THINGS //////////
```

My RelativeLayout that is the custom view for the actionbar.tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="64dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip"
android:layout_marginRight="-3dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabtitle"
    style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Tab Title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Due to my activity always get the data from service, i though it would be easilly with activity being recreated, but i had problems with service connection during the process because service bind and unbind are called and assynchronous.
As i already said, is my first time doing it, please tell me what is best thing to do.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Could you post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this line of code , in your activity , **before** the setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout) ;

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) ;
```

and for the android 3.2+ , you should also add this :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

[And study the documentation here!](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: Thank u very much, i did it (android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize") and didnt even implemented the onConfigurationChanges() but all the things in the screen are rotating better than expected. Honestly i dont even know what is happening but works great, except by some moments where the actual selected tab lost its view (i use a customview on tab) after the changing. It appears void, despite the other non selected still on. Due to dont know what is happening, i have no idea what to do. Pls help.

Comment: I put my custom tab view on the question.

Comment: When on debug mode on eclipse, it didnt happen, what made it yet more difficult to understand something.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What's exactly happening to your tabview ?